# executing runtime.getruntime in java is not creating json file

Tags: java, json, runtime

I am using:

```
    try{
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/Desktop/crt_json);
        p.waitFor(); 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("I caught: " + ex);
    }
```

to run a c++ file named **crt_json** that creates a json file.
when i run it through the terminal is working perfectly but when i run it through the java code the json file is not being created.
Also i know for a fact that the program **crt_json** is being executed beacuse it also does a couple of other things and it's doing every single one of them except creating the json file.
Does anyone know if there is a problem creating json files when executing a c++ file with runtime or something?

Comment: Where does it create the file? You may have to set the current working directory for the process.

Comment: the location of the file matters... java will not be able to create a file in a location where it doesn't have permissions to write to... check that

Comment: it already creates some .bmp files in the same directory. So i'm guessing it has permission to create files in that location. But for some weird reason the .json is not being created.

Comment: Have you tried adding `CMD /C` or `sh` for Windows/UNIX environment, as parameters before the actual command, in `exec()` ?

Answer (score 0):

The c file was being created in the "current folder" and the current folder was in a crazy directory so i changed the code so i could force it to be in a path of my choosing.